# Open and Close of same File multiple times vs Opening File for long time

Tags: java, performance, file

I am writing to a `File` whenever any change of content in `JTextArea` field.I have decided to open and close the file content each time as per the change event.

Something like ,

```
public void addToLogFile(String changeContent) {
    try {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(currentLogFile,true)));
        pw.print(changeContent);
        pw.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Instead of opening and closing the file each time, I thought may be we could open it at initial phase and dump content whenever required. Finally close it at the end phase.

**At Initial Phase of program:**

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(currentLogFile,true)));
```

Then somewhere in code, wherever needed,

```
pw.print(changeContent); // Most frequent usage
```

**At Final Phase of program:**

```
pw.close();
```

Which one will be more efficient ? Under what condition, Do I have to choose one ?

Comment: Keep it open, no question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More effective would definitely be opening the file once. Opening the file everytime is quite costly.

One case it may be useful is when new entries to the file happen once in a long while, so the OS doesn't need to hold open file handler.

Another case in which I would consider opening and closing it each time is when writes happen not so often and you want to let other processes write to the file. Or maybe when you want to ensure each entry is visible just after writing it, but then you should rather simply flush the buffer.

Answer (score 3):

Not keeping the file open would be an option if you have many of those textfields, where each one is assiciated with a different file. Then, if the number of text fields approaches the open file limit, chances are that your program cannot open any other files, sockets or whatever, when each of the fields would occupy one file descriptor.

But, of course, this is a purely theoretic consideration. The open files  limit is usually around 2000, and I hardly can imagine an application with 2000 text input fields.

That being said, early versions of the unix find utility took care to close and later re-open traversed directories, to avoid problems with file decriptors running out. But this was in the early days when the limit was 20 or so.